# Failure Message: "System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101",

Tags: apex, trigger

I am deploying my code to production and i am getting the below error

Failure Message: "System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101", Failure Stack Trace:

My trigger

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after delete, after insert, after undelete, 
after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        {
        EncryptURl.insertOpp(Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap.keySet());
        }
}
```

and my trigger class is

```
public static void insertOpp(Opportunity[] o,Set<id> newMapKeySet)
{

    list<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate =[select id,Encrypted_URL__c from Opportunity where id  IN :newMapKeySet];
    for(Opportunity op:oppsToUpdate){
        if(op.id != null){
            string oppid=op.id;
            Blob dataLead = Blob.valueOf(oppid);
            String b64Data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(dataLead);
            string oppURL =Label.PWV_FavoriteURL+'oId='+b64Data;
            op.Encrypted_URL__c =oppURL;
        }   
   }
    try{
    update oppsToUpdate;
    }catch(exception e){
            system.debug('DMl exception'+e);
     }

}
```

Can i know where i am going wrong ....

Answer (score 2):

As an always `System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101` is hard to find. Error does not return you place what is a problem but those that cause SOQL number 101. So you have to investigate ALL code around this action. Check your logs. Good luck :)

Btw I don't think you need query for `oppsToUpdate` as you have those in Trigger.new

Try something like this:

```
public static void insertOpp(Opportunity[] Opportunities){
    Opportunity[] opps = new Opportunity []{};
    // This is just in case you want only those 2 fields in  opportunities in your list
    for(Opportunity op:Opportunities){
        opps.add( new Opportunity(  Id = op.Id,
                                    Encrypted_URL__c = op.Encrypted_URL__c
                                  ));
    }

    for(Opportunity opp:opps){
        /* your actions*/
    }
    update opps;
}
```

Comment: i need update opportunity so on before insert it is not  possible because the record is null and to do an after i have to query the record other it is giving an error read only

Comment: isn't it recursion?

Comment: I think it is getting recursion.

Comment: list<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate =[select id,Encrypted_URL__c from Opportunity where id  IN :newMapKeySet];// i think the error is with this line when i commented i was able deploy it fine

Comment: how can i query without exceeding the limit

Comment: Check my post - see no query :)

Comment: i changed the logic accordingly but still i am getting the query exception when i am deploying it production

Comment: In that case one of actions must provide some query.
Or after update trigger? You must check it on your own. I don't belive anyone without access to your dev will be able to help